# turtlebot3 manipulation is not loading in gazebo

Tags: ros-noetic, turtlebot3, turtlebot-bringup, turtlebot-gazebo

I am trying to launch the turtlebot3 wth the open maniputor in gazebo [here](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/manipulation/#turtlebot3-with-openmanipulator)
But when I follow the instructions, I get the output below. The arm is white and I cannot send any commands to the robot or read the sensors. I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I think I am missing some package, but I am not sure what to install since it launches with no errors.

```
root@25a7563196e4:/workspaces/labs# roslaunch turtlebot3_manipulation_gazebo turtlebot3_manipulation_gazebo.launch 
    ... logging to /root/.ros/log/33f81b3c-791d-11ee-84c8-0242ac110002/roslaunch-25a7563196e4-1550.log
    Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
    Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
    Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
    
    xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option.
    started roslaunch server http://25a7563196e4:37317/
    
    SUMMARY
    ========
    
    PARAMETERS
     * /arm_controller/action_monitor_rate: 10
     * /arm_controller/constraints/goal_time: 0.6
     * /arm_controller/constraints/joint1/goal: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/constraints/joint1/trajectory: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/constraints/joint2/goal: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/constraints/joint2/trajectory: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/constraints/joint3/goal: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/constraints/joint3/trajectory: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/constraints/joint4/goal: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/constraints/joint4/trajectory: 0.1
     * /arm_controller/constraints/stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.05
     * /arm_controller/joints: ['joint1', 'joint...
     * /arm_controller/state_publish_rate: 25
     * /arm_controller/stop_trajectory_duration: 0.5
     * /arm_controller/type: position_controll...
     * /gazebo/enable_ros_network: True
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/gripper_sub/d: 1.0
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/gripper_sub/i: 0.1
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/gripper_sub/i_clamp: 0.2
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/gripper_sub/p: 300.0
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint1/d: 1.0
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint1/i: 0.1
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint1/i_clamp: 0.2
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint1/p: 300.0
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint2/d: 1.0
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint2/i: 0.1
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint2/i_clamp: 0.2
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint2/p: 300.0
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint3/d: 1.0
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint3/i: 0.1
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint3/i_clamp: 0.2
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint3/p: 300.0
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint4/d: 1.0
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint4/i: 0.1
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint4/i_clamp: 0.2
     * /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/joint4/p: 300.0
     * /gripper_controller/action_monitor_rate: 10
     * /gripper_controller/constraints/goal_time: 0.6
     * /gripper_controller/constraints/gripper/goal: 0.1
     * /gripper_controller/constraints/gripper/trajectory: 0.1
     * /gripper_controller/constraints/stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.05
     * /gripper_controller/gains/gripper/d: 1
     * /gripper_controller/gains/gripper/i: 1
     * /gripper_controller/gains/gripper/i_clamp: 1
     * /gripper_controller/gains/gripper/p: 100
     * /gripper_controller/joints: ['gripper']
     * /gripper_controller/state_publish_rate: 25
     * /gripper_controller/stop_trajectory_duration: 0.5
     * /gripper_controller/type: effort_controller...
     * /joint_state_controller/publish_rate: 1000
     * /joint_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...
     * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
     * /rosdistro: noetic
     * /rosversion: 1.16.0
     * /use_sim_time: True
    
    NODES
      /
        arm_controller_spawner (controller_manager/controller_manager)
        gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
        gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
        gripper_controller_spawner (controller_manager/controller_manager)
        joint_state_controller_spawner (controller_manager/controller_manager)
        spawn_gazebo_model (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)
    
    auto-starting new master
    process[master]: started with pid [1560]
    ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
    
    setting /run_id to 33f81b3c-791d-11ee-84c8-0242ac110002
    process[rosout-1]: started with pid [1572]
    started core service [/rosout]
    process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [1579]
    process[gazebo_gui-3]: started with pid [1583]
    process[spawn_gazebo_model-4]: started with pid [1588]
    process[joint_state_controller_spawner-5]: started with pid [1590]
    process[arm_controller_spawner-6]: started with pid [1591]
    process[gripper_controller_spawner-7]: started with pid [1592]
    [INFO] [1698887683.825984, 0.000000]: Loading model XML from ros parameter robot_description
    [INFO] [1698887683.829888, 0.000000]: Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
    [ INFO] [1698887683.987354159]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
    [ INFO] [1698887683.988197749]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
    [ INFO] [1698887684.050535409]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
    [ INFO] [1698887684.051321330]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo_gui/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
    [ INFO] [1698887684.457821464]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
    [ INFO] [1698887684.474927152]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
    [INFO] [1698887684.733870, 0.000000]: Calling service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
    [ INFO] [1698887685.512449419]: Camera Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/'
    [ INFO] [1698887685.518242272]: Camera Plugin (ns = /)  <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
    [INFO] [1698887685.644412, 0.000000]: Spawn status: SpawnModel: Successfully spawned entity
    [INFO] [1698887685.645458, 0.000000]: Waiting for service /gazebo/set_model_configuration
    [INFO] [1698887685.646938, 0.000000]: temporary hack to **fix** the -J joint position option (issue #93), sleeping for 1 second to avoid race condition.
    [ INFO] [1698887685.665390562]: Laser Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/'
    [ INFO] [1698887685.665476023]: Starting Laser Plugin (ns = /)
    [ INFO] [1698887685.666363273]: Laser Plugin (ns = /)  <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
    [ INFO] [1698887685.711666634]: Starting plugin DiffDrive(ns = //)
    [ INFO] [1698887685.711765664]: DiffDrive(ns = //): <rosDebugLevel> = na
    [ INFO] [1698887685.712439354]: DiffDrive(ns = //): <tf_prefix> = 
    [ INFO] [1698887685.713028735]: DiffDrive(ns = //): Advertise joint_states
    [ INFO] [1698887685.713446926]: DiffDrive(ns = //): Try to subscribe to cmd_vel
    [ INFO] [1698887685.714608096]: DiffDrive(ns = //): Subscribe to cmd_vel
    [ INFO] [1698887685.714907876]: DiffDrive(ns = //): Advertise odom on odom 
    [ INFO] [1698887685.728130572]: Loading gazebo_ros_control plugin
    [ INFO] [1698887685.728298512]: Starting gazebo_ros_control plugin in namespace: /
    [ INFO] [1698887685.728751003]: gazebo_ros_control plugin is waiting for model URDF in parameter [robot_description] on the ROS param server.
    [ INFO] [1698887685.878481885]: Loaded gazebo_ros_control.
    [ INFO] [1698887685.892675701]: MimicJointPlugin loaded! Joint: "gripper", Mimic joint: "gripper_sub", Multiplier: 1, Offset: 0, MaxEffort: 1, Sensitiveness: 0
    Loaded 'arm_controller'
    Loaded 'gripper_controller'
    Loaded 'joint_state_controller'
    [INFO] [1698887686.648566, 0.000000]: Calling service /gazebo/set_model_configuration
    [INFO] [1698887686.652708, 0.000000]: Set model configuration status: SetModelConfiguration: success
    [spawn_gazebo_model-4] process has finished cleanly
    log file: /root/.ros/log/33f81b3c-791d-11ee-84c8-0242ac110002/spawn_gazebo_model-4*.log
    ^C[gripper_controller_spawner-7] killing on exit
    [arm_controller_spawner-6] killing on exit
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

All I need to do it is hit the start button on the bottom.